# excel VBA double click go to cell value

Tags: vba, excel

i have the code that copy/pastes a value from a cell in a range to a target cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Range("A2:A1000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B1048568") = Target
        Cancel = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

What values do I need to change to do "goto" instead of copy/paste?
I have a list of values on column "A" and the same values as headers on cells "D:Z"
I want by double clicking on a cell in column "A" to go to the cell with the same value on the range "D:Z"

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the cell and then use the `Activate` method of that cell.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @StackFlowed, his question is how to go to a cell in a range.  My answer provides the solution to that.  `SO` is not really a rewrite-my-code-for-me site.

Comment: It provides a hint and not a solution.

Comment: @JasonMArcher, maybe you have a better answer?

Comment: You are changing the subject.